# Create folders based on filetypes in Vim

Tags: c++, vim

I recently discovered Vim and fell for it. I primarily code in Python and C++. The python part is done (although suggestions would be welcome :) ), but I am having trouble with C++.
I saw that vim can run Make commands, with appropriate arguments too. So I want Vim to create a build folder within the current project folder, whenever it detects a C file, if the build file doesn't exists. After some googling, I have tried this:

```
 BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp
    \ if empty(glob('build')) |
    \ call mkdir("build", "p") |
    \ endif
```

But  it doesn't seem to work or throw any errors. Any help would be appreciated. I am a complete newby to Vim, so excuse any silly errors.

Comment: This is a job for `make`, not for `vim`.

Comment: Could you please give the details of how to do it? Ideally, I would do something like this too, make a shortcut that would be similar to build and run shortcut of IDEs like VIsual Studio

Comment: @romainl, when we build out of the source directory, the makefile may not exist yet (as it's the case with CMake). In that case, we cannot rely on make to create the missing build directory.

Comment: @ParthaDas, why don't you create it on the fly instead of using an autocommand?

Comment: @LucHermitte, sorry I have no experience with C++ and CMake.

Comment: @romainl. The same may happen, with configure when we run `configure` (on a C project) outside the sources directory as well. This is not a typical use case, but I've seen it a few times. (Don't be sorry, BTW, this scenario is quite different from OP's: (s)he seem to consider single-file projects without any makefile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function! MkBuild(fname) abort            
    let root = finddir('.git', escape(fnamemodify(a:fname, ':p:h'), ' ') . ';')
    if root !=# '                         
        let build = fnamemodify(root, ':p:h') . (!exists('+shellslash') || &shellslash) ? '/' : '\') . 'build'              
        if !isdirectory(build)            
            call mkdir(build)             
        endif                             
    endif                                 
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp call MkBuild(expand('<amatch>'))
```

This piece of code tries to determine the root of your project by looking upwards for a directory named `.git`, then if it finds it creates a directory `build` in the root of the project.

Of course, you can replace the test for `.git` by something else.  F.i. to look upwards for a file named `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
let root = findfile('CMakeLists.txt', escape(fnamemodify(a:fname, ':p:h'), ' ') . ';')
```

Comment: I tried it out, but it says invalid expression for the fnamemodify line.
(Also, I think the check for root would be if != ' ' I'm sure it was just an unintentional typo. Just so that anyone in the future doesn't post about it.)

Comment: Okay, I turned off that line, thinking, since the directory needs to be built in the same path where the check is being made, trying to get the absolute path is redundant. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: @ParthaDas _it says invalid expression_ - Hard to tell why without the exact error message.  _Also, I think the check for root would be if != ' '_ - Nope, `!=#` is intended.  `!=#` is case-sensitive comparison, while `!=` depends on `ignorecase`.  The first one is marginally faster.